# Too many appcompat_v7 versions in workspace

Tags: java, android, eclipse, workspace, android-appcompat

I noticed a lot of these appcompat_v7 versions in my workspace, are they really necessary and can i delete them?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9BV1pik.png]

Comment: yes, you can, provided that you don't need to modify them.

Comment: This occurs because everytime you start a new project that requires appcompat, Eclipse automatically generates the project into your workspace so that it can be used as a library.  To avoid this, don't mark a project as needing appcompat and instead manually add appcompat as a library to the project.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this now? Can i delete all of them but one, then add the remaining one as a library to all my projects?

Comment: You should be able to delete them and leave only one.  If anything you can try and see if you get the results you want.  You might need to play around which libraries you're importing.

Comment: Had to remove older versions in libs folders too but it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to safely delete all of them but one. Keep the latest one.